# .LESS how to add width with duration?

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to create a loading bar, which will go longer on width with duration, with `.less` and here's my layout:

```
    <section class="home-page container">
        <div class="home-content col span_8_of_8">
            <div class="preloader-1">
                <em class="loader"></em>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

The `LESS` part is here:

```
    div.preloader-1 {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 1px;
        border: thin solid #d5d5d5;

        em.loader {
            background: @main-red;
            width: @preload_width;
            .addBar('width', 5s);
        }
    }

@body-font: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
@heading-font: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

@flash-red: #ff0000;
@flash-green: #40bc88;

@main-green: #40bc88;

/* preloader 1 settings */

@preload_width: 10%;
@preloader1_class: 'preloader-1';

.addBar(@property, @duration, @style:ease-in-out) when(@preload_width <= 100%) {
    -webkit-transition-property: @property;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: @duration;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: @style;

    -moz-transition-property: @property;  
    -moz-transition-duration: @duration;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: @style;

    -ms-transition-property: @property;  
    -ms-transition-duration: @duration;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: @style;

    -o-transition-property: @property;  
    -o-transition-duration: @duration;
    -o-transition-timing-function: @style;

    transition-property: @property;  
    transition-duration: @duration;
    transition-timing-function: @style;

    @preload_width: (@preload_width + 10%);
}
```

Error came out like this:

```
>> SyntaxError: Recursive variable definition for @preload_width in app\assets\s
tylesheets\less\front\preloader_1.less on line 9, column 3:
>> 8            width: @preload-width;
>> 9            .addBar('width', 5s);
>> 10   }
```

I'm guessing it's on the `when`part in the less, but i'm not sure how to fix, can anyone explain to me how to do it? Thanks. (Oh yeah, the solution must not include `JS` or anything else, only pure `.less`)

Comment: `@preload-width` doesn't seem to have been defined. Do you mean `@preload_width` and might you need to define this above where it is used?

Comment: it is defined, actually the code i write here is backwards, variables comes first and then the `div.preloader-1` code, i already checked that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem is really here:

```
@preload_width: (@preload_width + 10%);
```

- LESS can't handle variable redefinitions (e.g. changing a variable's value)
- You're trying to create a variable with its own value.

Both of these problems can be solved by changing your new variable's name.

Comment: well ok i changed it to: `@property: @preload_width + 10%;`, no errors, but the width is not added as if nothing happen

Comment: @user2002495 Because you define it in the bottom of your rule and don't use it anywhere. AFAIK, there is no way to increment things in LESS, because it is compiled before being read by the client, so it doesn't has data about the number of elements or anything like that.